# How to workaround OSRM map match {"message":"Too many trace coordinates","code":"TooBig"}

Tags: open-source-routing-machine, map-matching

I have created a web page to test OSRM map match service (running locally in the latest osrm/osrm-backend docker image), before starting to integrate it into my app.

And when sending just 4 locations (by clicking with the mouse) the map matching works well, but when I send 168 real car locations (by copy-pasting JSON data), then it fails with `{"message":"Too many trace coordinates","code":"TooBig"}` 400 Bad Request:

[image: animated open street map]

I have also tested both links against https://router.project-osrm.org with the same result:

- [4 locations](https://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/10.738617,52.417409;10.737587,52.428245;10.736987,52.437352;10.733468,52.444416?overview=simplified&radiuses=50;50;50;50&generate_hints=false&skip_waypoints=true&gaps=ignore&annotations=nodes&geometries=geojson) work well
- [168 locations](https://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/driving/9.535078,50.944164;9.536036,50.943869;9.536951,50.943518;9.537805,50.943120;9.538589,50.942679;9.539302,50.942196;9.539936,50.941679;9.540493,50.941131;9.540974,50.940552;9.541367,50.939948;9.541666,50.939331;9.541912,50.938694;9.542148,50.938044;9.542391,50.937387;9.542632,50.936729;9.542879,50.936071;9.543139,50.935416;9.543346,50.934769;9.543483,50.934124;9.543601,50.933485;9.543716,50.932852;9.543833,50.932219;9.543947,50.931584;9.544058,50.930948;9.544171,50.930310;9.544285,50.929672;9.544403,50.929043;9.544543,50.928427;9.544774,50.927836;9.545107,50.927277;9.545525,50.926755;9.546023,50.926270;9.546602,50.925815;9.547261,50.925404;9.547989,50.925025;9.548733,50.924642;9.549472,50.924256;9.550250,50.923905;9.551080,50.923621;9.551961,50.923387;9.552855,50.923176;9.553736,50.922941;9.554601,50.922663;9.555449,50.922318;9.556231,50.921901;9.556936,50.921428;9.557600,50.920911;9.558263,50.920387;9.558936,50.919856;9.559631,50.919315;9.560351,50.918783;9.561146,50.918268;9.562016,50.917780;9.562932,50.917299;9.563860,50.916819;9.564793,50.916341;9.565702,50.915873;9.566604,50.915405;9.567495,50.914943;9.568384,50.914486;9.569267,50.914030;9.570142,50.913577;9.571019,50.913129;9.571903,50.912674;9.572798,50.912221;9.573704,50.911784;9.574636,50.911369;9.575579,50.910990;9.576552,50.910636;9.577536,50.910298;9.578533,50.909960;9.579511,50.909626;9.580492,50.909292;9.581465,50.908943;9.582363,50.908551;9.583187,50.908102;9.583915,50.907601;9.584556,50.907048;9.585086,50.906476;9.585539,50.905850;9.585866,50.905204;9.586066,50.904537;9.586150,50.903854;9.586122,50.903176;9.585972,50.902494;9.585714,50.901825;9.585333,50.901171;9.584830,50.900531;9.584288,50.899891;9.583748,50.899253;9.583236,50.898626;9.582748,50.898005;9.582287,50.897419;9.581804,50.896836;9.581312,50.896257;9.580791,50.895665;9.580274,50.895065;9.579855,50.894447;9.579544,50.893806;9.579347,50.893153;9.579261,50.892488;9.579288,50.891857;9.579434,50.891237;9.579701,50.890633;9.580076,50.890048;9.580542,50.889498;9.581104,50.888987;9.581742,50.888518;9.582459,50.888096;9.583238,50.887734;9.584067,50.887428;9.584937,50.887177;9.585830,50.886990;9.586768,50.886861;9.587715,50.886794;9.588671,50.886771;9.589647,50.886763;9.590616,50.886757;9.591549,50.886716;9.592466,50.886608;9.593363,50.886425;9.594239,50.886176;9.595066,50.885873;9.595834,50.885515;9.596533,50.885110;9.597166,50.884660;9.597722,50.884166;9.598229,50.883651;9.598726,50.883143;9.599237,50.882625;9.599745,50.882102;9.600198,50.881552;9.600554,50.880987;9.600812,50.880408;9.600972,50.879809;9.601021,50.879201;9.601020,50.878585;9.601030,50.877960;9.601033,50.877329;9.600980,50.876712;9.600817,50.876095;9.600563,50.875508;9.600231,50.874975;9.599786,50.874439;9.599243,50.873935;9.598625,50.873458;9.597985,50.872990;9.597345,50.872521;9.596729,50.872034;9.596167,50.871533;9.595653,50.871028;9.595212,50.870513;9.594856,50.869990;9.594551,50.869481;9.594234,50.868982;9.593894,50.868468;9.593543,50.867938;9.593184,50.867396;9.592812,50.866835;9.592443,50.866272;9.592087,50.865727;9.591737,50.865195;9.591419,50.864668;9.591154,50.864147;9.590906,50.863620;9.590662,50.863091;9.590408,50.862561;9.590158,50.862027?overview=simplified&radiuses=50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50;50&generate_hints=false&skip_waypoints=true&gaps=ignore&annotations=nodes&geometries=geojson) fail with 400 Bad Request

The POST method is not supported by OSRM backend, so I have not tried it.

It seems to me that having 168 locations in a real life use case should be nothing unusual for map matching.

For example, when someone returns from a day long bycicle trip and wants to see it on the map.

My question is: do you encounter the same [issue #6612](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/6612) with OSRM map matching and what are your strategies to workaround it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set service specific payload sizes on engine boot via `osrm-routed` CLI flags¹:

```
docker run -t -i -p <port:port> -v "${PWD}:/<pwd> <path/to>/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm <MLD/CH> --max-matching-size <value> <path/to/graph>.osrm
```

where `--max-matching-size <value>` defines the allowed input trace size.

---

¹ AFAIK these are undocumented except for in *man*, i.e. `osrm_routed --help`

Comment: Running the docker image with `docker run --name osrm -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v c:/repos:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld --max-matching-size 1000 /data/germany-latest.osrm` has helped me, thank you